# tensorflow/tools/pip_package not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am installing Tensorflow from source I am following this guide ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source)).

Step1: Install Bazel:

```
wget "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.24.1/bazel-0.24.1-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh"

chmod +x bazel-0.24.1-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
./bazel-0.24.1-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh --user
```

Step 2: Download Tensorflow

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
cd tensorflow
```

Step3: Configure the build

```
./configure
```

Config parameters used:

> ajinkyas-MacBook-Pro:tensorflow ajinkyabobade$ ./configure  WARNING:
>   Running Bazel server needs to be killed, because the startup options
>   are different. WARNING: --batch mode is deprecated. Please instead
>   explicitly shut down your Bazel server using the command "bazel
>   shutdown". You have bazel 0.24.1 installed. Please specify the
>   location of python. [Default is
>   /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7]:
>   /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7
>
> Found possible Python library paths:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is
>   [/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages]
>   /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   Do you wish to build TensorFlow with XLA JIT support? [y/N]: n No XLA
>   JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
>
> Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL SYCL support? [y/N]: n No
>   OpenCL SYCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
>
> Do you wish to build TensorFlow with ROCm support? [y/N]: n No ROCm
>   support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
>
> Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]: n No CUDA
>   support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
>
> Do you wish to download a fresh release of clang? (Experimental)
>   [y/N]: n Clang will not be downloaded.
>
> Do you wish to build TensorFlow with MPI support? [y/N]: n No MPI
>   support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
>
> Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel
>   option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native
>   -Wno-sign-compare]:  -march=native -Wno-sign-compare
>
> Would you like to interactively configure ./WORKSPACE for Android
>   builds? [y/N]: n Not configuring the WORKSPACE for Android builds.
>
> Do you wish to build TensorFlow with iOS support? [y/N]: n No iOS
>   support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
>
> Preconfigured Bazel build configs. You can use any of the below by
>   adding "--config=<>" to your build command. See .bazelrc for more
>   details.  --config=mkl            # Build with MKL support.
>     --config=monolithic     # Config for mostly static monolithic build.
>     --config=gdr            # Build with GDR support.   --config=verbs
>     # Build with libverbs support.  --config=ngraph         # Build with
>   Intel nGraph support.     --config=numa           # Build with NUMA
>   support.  --config=dynamic_kernels    # (Experimental) Build kernels into
>   separate shared objects. Preconfigured Bazel build configs to DISABLE
>   default on features:  --config=noaws          # Disable AWS S3
>   filesystem support.   --config=nogcp          # Disable GCP support.
>     --config=nohdfs         # Disable HDFS support.     --config=noignite
>     # Disable Apache Ignite support.    --config=nokafka        # Disable
>   Apache Kafka support.     --config=nonccl         # Disable NVIDIA NCCL
>   support. Configuration finished

Step4: Bazel build

```
ajinkyas-MacBook-Pro:tensorflow ajinkyabobade$ bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: Skipping '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package': no such package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': BUILD file not found on package path
WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: no such package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': BUILD file not found on package path
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.962s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

In ERROR I get ERROR: Skipping '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package': no such package. Where as I just installed this same package. How to remove this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1: Install all dependencies:

```
pip install -U  pip six numpy wheel setuptools mock
pip install -U  keras_applications==1.0.6 --no-deps
pip install -U  keras_preprocessing==1.0.5 --no-deps
```

Step2: Install Bazel

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
wget "https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.24.1/bazel-0.24.1-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh"
chmod +x bazel-0.24.1-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
./bazel-0.24.1-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh --user
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
bazel version
```

Step3: Install Tensorflow:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
cd tensorflow
./configure
```

Step4: Config parameters

type `$ which python3` and then enter path of python 3.6 in configuration parameters,
say no to all other questions
please note bazel version 0.24.1 darwin is for MacOS

Step5: `bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`